# Codeigniter - Using environments with different hosts

Tags: codeigniter

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I have started using version control (git) for my website which is using CodeIgniter.

Everytime i transfer files from my localhost host to my live server, i always have to go through all my files and change the config details.

I came across a post saying i could do all this with the ENVIRONMENT settings in the index.php file automatically based on the SERVER_NAME.

Has anybody done this before? if so, would it be possible to let me know how its done properly?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a start (index.php):

```
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == 'devserver1' || $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == 'devserver2')
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
else
    define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

Then, whenever you need it, you check for the ENVIRONMENT constant (for example, different database settings, etc.). For localhost, simply check if the server is 'localhost' (`$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] == 'localhost'`), or whichever virtual host name you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use environment variables

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

This will allow you to get the environment instead of hard coding the information in your code

This may also help you out

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch04_06.htm

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still needing help with this, but I had this issue a while ago and released a CodeIgniter module which is designed to automatically handle multiple environments.

I'm shameful to be plugging myself, but it's saved me lots of editing and it might be of use to anyone else that'll read this post in the future.

Here's the link to the Git repo: https://github.com/jedkirby/ci-multi-environments and this is a brief explanation of why and how I made the module: http://jedkirby.com/blog/2012/11/codeigniter-multiple-development-environments